# Disable the VBA code editor window in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am looking for a possibility to add an additional level of security to my Excel projects.

We have multiple users. Some who know (and are meant to) the password that unlocks the VBA macros. Others are not meant to be able to access these.

I'm not sure if someone has the password that shouldn't (changing the password hasn't stopped tampering) so i would like to disable the VBA editing window for any user not approved.  I can't find any way to do this though, is it possible?

I can't disable the save option as all users need to save data.

I have tried to disable the ribbon icons etc, but with no sucess. It is still possible to open the code window with Alt+F11.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am coming from Excel 2003, but this concept should work for you as well. You could think of

- trapping the Alt-F11 key (`Application.OnKey "%{F11}" "MyNullSub"`) plus
- disable the relevant menu entries (`Application.CommandBars(...).FindControl(ID:=..).OnAction = "MyNullSub"`)

with

```
Sub MyNullSub()
' do nothing
End Sub
```

as a dependency of an entry in the registry that needs to be present (`GetSetting(...)`), but this will only help until this additional secret is spread around in the same way the (changed) passwords apparently did.

Comment: How will approved users access the VB editor? Also, if an unapproved user chooses not to allow macros upon opening the workbook, this trapping will not work.

Comment: @Jean as I wrote: as a dependency on a registry setting, i.e. the trap will only be laid out if a certain registry key is NOT present. Superusers will be told to set a certain key below "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Settings" .... this is a second layer of protection .... as I said above this is also not a super secure and fake proof mechanism but better than nothing

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I'm sure the registry key trick will spread *much* more slowly than the password! +1 because I think there is no good answer to this question but this comes pretty close!

Comment: @Jean I was interested and studied the case a bit further. I started using the authentication mechanism of a database. i.e. the user has to enter UN and PW and VBA tries to connect and fire a dummy query. If it succeeds - good, if not exit. Works pretty cool and removes some of the headache. This is pretty safe due to the underlying network protocol as well. I will expand this and try to get authenticated by a secure website (SSL)